# Translating code into mathematical formula: conditionals

Tags: functions

How would I translate this code into a mathematical formula?

```
myset={4,2,5,26,8,1,2}, d0=[], d1=[], dnp1=[]
for i in range(myset):
    if   i==0: d0=myset[i]
    elif i==1: d1=myset[i]
    else:      dnp1+=myset[i]
```

(a $\LaTeX$ example would be great)

Comment: I have received this solution over IRC, it is useful but being able to more explicitly do an `if` `elif` type thing would be better: $$ d1 = myset_1, d0 = myset_0, dnp1 = \sum_{i >= 2} myset_i $$

Comment: If $i \in \{4, 2, 5, 26, 8, 1, 2\}$ then how come you test for $i = 0$?! $i$ will never be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution (I devised myself):

$$ \sum_{i}^{\text{myset}} d_0=\{ \unicode{x27E6}i==0\unicode{x27E7}\ i \},\ d_1=\{ \unicode{x27E6}i==1\unicode{x27E7}\ i \},\ d_{np1}=\{ \unicode{x27E6}i>1\unicode{x27E7}\ i \} $$

Comment: Please delete this answer, edit your question and this info inside your question.

Comment: @J.D. you know it's kosher to answer your own question, right?

Comment: @J.M. Sure. But this question is two folded (1) how do I formulate it? (2) is my following *attempt* correct? Answering (2) is much easier if all OP's *attempts* are in 1 place: the question body.